# Rails eager loading of counts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Eager loading is nice with the include attribute

```
Post.find(:all, :include => :author)
```

I'm wondering if you can also eager load counts, like if I wanted to get the number of comments for each post, without loading all the comments themselves?

Maybe something like

```
Post.find(:all, :include => [:author, "count(comments)")
```

I suppose I could use a count_cache column.  But doing it all in an include would be really beautiful, if it's possible.

Extra bonus points if someone can show how to not only get the count, but put some conditions too, like count of only posts which have been approved.

Comment: This was later expanded in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908878/how-do-i-get-rails-to-eager-load-counts
Which is strongly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870521/how-will-activerelation-affect-rails-includes-s-capabilities (which is how I found it.)

Answer (score -8, accepted):

In MySQL at least, it is faster to do these as two separate calls because you get to avoid the join.  I know this doesn't answer your question, but it seems like you're trying to get better speed and doing

```
Post.find ...
```

Then

```
post.comments.count
```

Is faster and more memory efficient (for the database) than if you retrieve both in one query.

Comment: Well, one of the major reasons to use eager loading is to avoid N+1 queries.

Comment: This induces an N+1 query and doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 35):

they should already be loaded use

```
post.comments.length
```

I was having this same problem because I was using .count

Comment: I don't think this is what he is looking for. This will load all the entries in the comments association and then count them. He wants to use SQL to eagerly pull the count without loading the objects. (Or at least that's how I understand it).

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. On and index page of posts where I'd like to iterate over the collection and display the count of comments - this avoids firing a count request in each cycle (Provided the comments have been eager loaded together with the posts). Thanks :-)

Answer (score 7):

Building off of avaynshtok's answer, the following technique should just make 2 database calls.

```
# ./app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

def index
  # First load the posts
  @posts = Post.all

  # Then you can load a hash of author counts grouped by post_id
  # Rails 4 version:
  @comment_counts = Comment.group(:post_id).count
  # Rails 3 version:
  # @comment_counts = Comment.count(:group => :post_id)
end
```

Then in your view

```
<!-- ./app/views/posts/index.html.erb  -->

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <!-- reference the count by the post.id -->
  post_count: <%= @comment_counts[post.id] %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Comment.count(:group => :post)
```

To filter by conditions:

```
Comment.count(:group => :post, :conditions => {:approved => true })
```

These will return hashes with posts as keys and the number of comments as values.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for.  Yes, you can do it in a separate call like this.  But I don't think you can do them in an association like I wanted.  Probably have to use count_cache column.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this challenge and solved it this way:

```
def trainee_counts
   @trainee_counts ||= Hash[Trainee.group(:klass_id).count]
end

   # where the count is needed
   trainee_counts[klass_id].to_i
```

One call to database and does not load trainees.